# xmlhttp breaking in IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9, xmlhttprequest

```
echo 'function get_estrategias(estrategia,fase){
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            $("#descripciones select").append(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "../resources/get_estrategias.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1");
    parameters="estrategia="+estrategia+"&fase="+fase;
    xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}'
```

This code breaks in IE9. It throws error code C00CE56E 'unknown encoding' or something similar: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304625

I have no idea how to fix this, I'm learning ajax with a crude javascript base i know, but I have a feeling this is just another one of those IE bugs that i cant seem to know how to google.

UPDATE

As somebody mentioned, I tried this using solely jquery.

```
echo 'function get_estrategias(estrategia,fase){
            $.ajax({
                            url: \'../resources/get_estrategias.php\',
                            type: \'POST\',
                            dataType: \'html\',
                            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1",
                            data:{estrategia :estrategia,fase:fase},
                            success:function(data, textStatus, xhr){$("#descripciones select").append(data);},  
                            error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {alert(errorThrown+\'\n\'+status+\'\n\'+xhr.statusText); }
           });
    }';
```

I ended up with the same naggy error c00ce56e. That last error function I added after reading https://forum.jquery.com/topic/fix-jquery-ajax-errors-in-ie#14737000003545233
It produced a popup containing the following

```
 [object error]
 error
 [object error]
```

In all cases, I have tried adding 'AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1' and 'default_charset = "ISO-8859-1" ' to my http.conf and php.ini files respectively on my localhost, to no avail.
If this helps narrow down the problem, or if anyone has any inkling of how to fix the problem, please dont hesitate to say so :(

Comment: I think you might want to switch to a more cleaner approach by using Jquery post method.

Comment: if your learning this stuff from new, and although its important to get the fundamentals - jQuery the javascript library will save you a lot of time - its cross browsers and takes into account different versions of IE

Comment: Why are you setting the encoding? charset=ISO-8859-1